# Creating a range of numbers in an sql subquery

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a better way to generate a range of numbers in SQL than below? I'm using MySql.

```
SELECT tens.x + ones.x + 1
FROM
(SELECT 0 x UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 x UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 x UNION ALL
 ...
 SELECT 9 x ) ones

CROSS JOIN

(SELECT 0 x UNION ALL
 SELECT 10 x UNION ALL
 SELECT 20 x UNION ALL
 ...
 SELECT 90 x ) tens;
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @ammoQ - MySQL, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to do that in Oracle is to abuse the rownum pseudocolumn:

```
select rownum from all_objects where rownum<=100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Sql server 2005+ you can make use of CTEs

```
DECLARE @Start INT, @End INT

SELECT  @Start = 0, @End = 100000

;WITH Numbers AS (
        SELECT  @Start Num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  Num + 1
        FROM    Numbers
        WHERE   Num < @End
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Numbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Just be aware that the default maximum number of recursions is 100. This can be changed to  maximum of 32767 by calling: option (maxrecursion 32767). see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: Try that query, it goes past 32767 as specified by @End = 100000

Comment: true, my bad somehow I didn't notice that when OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) is specified there is no limit on the recursions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-srf.html) allows you to use:

```
select * from generate_series(2,4);
 generate_series
-----------------
               2
               3
               4
```

That is specific for the PostgresSQL engine. But it shouldn't be to hard to write a stored proedure for your data base.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `loop`? like

```
BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;
         insert into mytable(id) values(a);
         IF a=1000 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
```

Modified  from [Mysql For Loop](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/for.shtml)

Pardon me if the syntax is wrong as I am a pure SQL SERVER guy(: